# How do I use an asp.net user control in another user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, ascx

I have a user control (`gallery.ascx`) and I want to use the `photo.ascx` control in the gallery control.  I've added this register at the top of `gallery.ascx`, but it still can't find photo:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ssctrl" TagName="photo" Src="controls/photo.ascx" %>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible your gallery control is also in the controls folder, making the Src attribute incorrect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering, the Register is correct, my photo user control tag was just not formed properly.  I did have it as:

```
<ssctrl:photo ID="Photo" Key="<%# Eval("PageTemplatePK") %>" runat="server" />
```

and the Key property needed to use single quotes instead of double quotes because it was using an Eval expression:

```
<ssctrl:photo ID="Photo" Key='<%# Eval("PageTemplatePK") %>' runat="server" />
```

After that, it worked.