# CS0103: The name does not exist in the current context, For all controls in page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, custom-controls, ascx

I have imported a custom control to ASP.NET (C#), the control name is `HijriGregDatePicker.ascx` which has a pop-up calendar on both Islamic and Gregorian Calendars. My Problem when Compiling `HijriGregDatePicker.ascx.cs` I receive many errors of the type

> Error CS0103  The name 'ctlCalendarLocalized' does not exist in the
>   current context   certificate \certificate\HijriGregDatePicker.ascx.cs

While inside the ASCX file the calendar exists as below:its inside a DIV in a PANEL

```
<asp:Calendar ID="ctlCalendarLocalized" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
                BorderColor="White" 
                Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="125px"  
                Width="275px" BorderWidth="1px" NextPrevFormat="FullMonth" 
                ShowDayHeader="True" ShowNextPrevMonth="False"
                OnSelectionChanged="ctlCalendarLocalized_SelectionChanged">
                <DayHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="7pt"  Font-Names="Tahoma" />
                <NextPrevStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" 
                    ForeColor="#333333" />
                <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
                <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#333399" ForeColor="White" />
                <TitleStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" 
                    BorderWidth="1px" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="#333399" BorderStyle="Ridge" Font-Names="sans-serif" />
                <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
</asp:Calendar>
```

One of the solutions I found on the web was importing all Web references like below

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

But this didn't help, another solution was the inheritance in `HijriGregDatePicker.ascx`

Which was like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HijriGregDatePicker.ascx.cs" 
Inherits="HijriGregDatePicker.ascx"  %>
```

I tried removing the inheritance tag, but still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Inherits="HijriGregDatePicker.ascx"` property assignment is totally wrong and causing non-existent control name errors (you cannot use ASCX file extension as inheritance base to another user control). Use proper class name which has same name to code-behind file namespace like example below:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="HijriGregDatePicker.ascx.cs" 
Inherits="YourNamespace.HijriGregDatePicker" %>
```

Also worth to note that `UserControl` class inheritance does not include front-end visual elements like `asp:Calendar`, you need to use `Register` directive to use/show that base calendar control inside another user control (see [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251289/how-do-i-use-an-asp-net-user-control-in-another-user-control)):

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dtp" TagName="HijriGregDatePicker" Src="HijriGregDatePicker.ascx" %>

<dtp:HijriGregDatePicker ID="datepicker" runat="server" ...>
</dtp:HijriGregDatePicker>
```

Related issue: [How to inherit a UserControl from another UserControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218640/how-to-inherit-a-usercontrol-from-another-usercontrol)

Comment: Sounds like the namespace is missing. Try replace `CodeBehind` to `CodeFile` and make sure the provided namespace is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an ascx file, you may not necessarily use a code behind. Create a script right in the ascx page

```
<script runat="server">

</script>
```

When you add runat="server", the script won't appear in the browser source code. 
To avoid mistakes, use intellisence to create new control for `OnSelectionChange=""`